# How to use Push on Android Messanger?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, push, messenger

I want make Android messenger

This messenger is networking with Chat Server on Online Game.

Actually, GameChatServer is misbecome Android messenger.
because this server use be binary chat networking

So, I'm made messenger Chat Server, it have used GCM push.

but i listen to possibly loss by GCM.

Than i'm searching at few messenger Solution.

1. GCM listening in Background -> Notification -> Launch App -> Request ChatData on ChatServer
2. Long Polling in Background 
   -> Input chatdata in Background -> Notification -> Launch App -> load local database
3. Every few seconds(10s, 20s) polling in Background 
   -> Input chatdata in Background -> Notification -> Launch App -> load local database

I think this way is very burden up.

Is there another way?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, polling is discouraged because it drains battery. Push is the way to go. Not sure where you heard about GCM losing messages

Comment: @e4c5 I heard GCM Message loss 20%. it's not true?

Comment: There was such an issue in the early days

Comment: How is compliance? However, even if the loss of 0.1% is not available, the same key will be the same.

Comment: Compliance with what? So do you think it's possible to make a home made solution that beats Google's delivery rate? If you are really concerned about loss there is always delivery reciepts.